# Creating unordered list in a DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV. I want to dynamically generate a bulleted list inside the DIV using jQuery with a items list I have with me

```
for (cnt = 0; cnt < someList.length; cnt++) {
  someList[cnt].FirstName + ":" + someList[cnt].LastName + "<br/>"
  // what to write here?
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? : someList[cnt].FirstName + ":" + someList[cnt].LastName + "<br/>"

Comment: I am looping through the list and want to display the output of someList[cnt].FirstName and someList[cnt].LastName as an unordered list. There are 5 items in my list (someList), thus 5 bullets should be created

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Keeping things as simple as possible. Using your existing javascript, You would just need to add this:

```
$('#myDiv').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
for (cnt = 0; cnt < someList.length; cnt++) {
  $("#newList").append("<li>"+someList[cnt].FirstName + ":" + someList[cnt].LastName+"</li>");
}
```

Since your HTML already has the DIV:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: FirstName and LastName are not HTML-encoded.  This is a potential risk for injection.  Also, names may not be displayed correctly if they contain special characters like 'Amy & Bob'.  Here is my suggestion... 


$('<li/>').text(someList[cnt].FirstName + someList[cnt].LastName).appendTo('#newList');

Answer (score 6):

Script:

```
$(function(){
    someList = [ {FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith"} ,
                 {FirstName: "Will", LastName: "Brown"} ]

    $("#target").append("<ul id='list'></ul>");
    $.each(someList, function(n, elem) {
       $("#list").append("<li>" + elem.FirstName + " : " + elem.LastName + "</li>");
    });
});
```

and html:

```
<div id="target" />
```

Comment: How do I write this in the $.each you suggest

someList.d[i].FirstName

Comment: Thanks for your solution..I used the for loop and did it!

Comment: How is your array formed? $.each can iterate both arrays and hashes. When iterating arrays you can get both the element (elem) and the index (n) in the callback. If your array contains array elements, you need to call $.each inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

hacky

```
var list = "<ul>"
for (cnt = 0; cnt < someList.length; cnt++) {
    list += "<li>" + someList[cnt].FirstName + ":" + someList[cnt].LastName + "</li>"
}
list += "</ul>";
```

no even bothering with creating dom objects properly :)